# CSS not loading in Facebook's embedded, in-app browser on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, https

For whatever reason, after changing my client's site to HTTPS, all of their links display without CSS when viewed through Facebook's embedded browser. This is also the case with links on their Instagram story and I suspect they use the same technology.

This is ONLY an issue with Facebook / Instagram's native browser. I've debugged this in react's webview and every mobile browser I could think of and the site works perfectly fine.

There are no mixed content errors either.

I know Facebook doesn't have support (oh joy), but it sure would be nice to get some help with this.

Steps to replicate:

1. Go to Rapzilla.com's Facebook page on your mobile Facebook app.
2. Click any link back to the website.
3. See that site loads without CSS.

Comment: Something similar happens to me, in my case it does not recognize some properties such as `row-gap`, so I chose to use `margin`, it must be because the Facebook mobile browser is not updated